# sql & pdo syntax error?

Tags: php, pdo

i have a pdo statement for select all rows for  row count.... i keep getting this error "Call to member function execute() on Boolean" ...i have tripple checked my statement and database table but cant find anything wrong

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_profile WHERE email=:email");
            var_dump($connection->error);
            $stmt->execute(":email",$email);
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Var dump error says there is a syntax error here " :email" ..but i cant seem to see it...and its doing this through out my PDO code

Comment: There is no `PDOStatement::error` (that's `mysqli_`, not PDO), it's `PDOStatement::errorInfo()`. And you'd get a syntax-error with the placeholder `:email` if you're using `mysqli_` as the connection. So that begs the question - what are you connecting with?

Comment: @Qirel which is what I wrote/asked similarly earlier but they just upped and left the question so I said to myself: *"Pfffft..., fine."* so I deleted my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: ^ I voted to soon. Had I know that from that comment below, I would have closed this.

Answer (score 2):

The [`execute` function of PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) expect to get array of parameters

```
public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )
```

This is how you should use it in your code:

```
$stmt->execute( [":email" => $email] );
```

Comment: thanks but its not working...i even tried a different binding syntax "bind_param (":email",$email") " but still it says the error is in the statement

Comment: without the error you get it's impossible to help

Comment: `bind_param` gave it away, you're connecting with `mysqli_connect()` aren't you? @codex

Comment: @Derek ooow yes how could i be blind sided...you right Derek it worked...changed the db connection to PDO thanks again